# Python Tkinter project

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, computer-science

I'm working on a final for python. My goal is to make a code that uses Tkinter to ask the user to input the answer to a math problem using an entry box then press submit. I want to be able to have python do something depending on whether the answer is right or wrong, but I'm not sure how to do this with Tkinter. How do I make it "check" the answer? For example,

```
ent = Entry(pyfinal)
btn = Button(pyfinal, text="Submit", bg="#000000")
lbl = Label(pyfinal, text="What is the answer to 5 x 5?")
```

If I was using regular python, I would do this,

```
ent = int(input('What is 5 x 5? '))
if ent == int ('25'):
    print ("correct")
else:
    print ("wrong, try again.")
```

How would I do that with Tkinter while keeping it all in the Tkinter window?
Thanks

Comment: So ... you basically ask us to write your final exam for you? If you just want some pointers: Add a `command` callback to your Button, see e.g. [here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/button.html).

Comment: you can associate a command with a button. Put the check in the command.

Comment: No I'm not asking you to write it. I'm asking for help with some commands. Why do you think I didn't put up a full code? Also, I know about the command thing but I want it to print in the window not in the python module

Comment: Then try posting a working(not quite working/runnable) example of what you tried, and clearly state what's wrong.

Comment: What we are looking for is a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In this case, we would like to see a simple (but complete) program that displays a `tkinter` window with a label, text box, and button. We also want to see how you tried to get the value from the text box when the button was pressed. You may have to put this code in a separate file so that you don't interfere with your current progress. Once we have this minimal code, we can show you what to do next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using if statements for example:

```
Mp = Answer to math problem
Answer = What user wrote

If Mp == Answer:
     Lbl = Label("You are right")
     Lbl2.pack()
     Lbl.after(3000, lambda: label.destroy())
Else:
     Lbl2 = Label("You are wrong')
     Lbl2.pack()
     Lbl2.after(3000, lambda: label2.destroy())
```

Only write the .after statement if you want to delete this label in a certain amount of time